# How to remember open/closed state of div using cookie or localStorage?

Tags: javascript, magento, cookies, local-storage

I'm trying to keep a div closed until someone clicks it then remember if it is either open or closed.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<input id="chk1" type="button" value="Click here"/>

<div id="box1" style="display:none">
    <!-- HTML STUFF HERE -->
</div>

<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#chk1').click(function() {
        $('#box1').slideToggle('200'); 
        localStorage.setItem('show', 'true');
      });
    });
</script>
```

It works except it doesn't remember the div open/closed state.

I would like to do it without adding any more scripts if possible.

Comment: You need to first check for the value stored in the `localStorage` by using `localStorage.getItem('show')` and check if it's true and false. Then show/hide the div initially accordingly. Also, you are not toggling the value of `show` to `true/false`. You show toggle the value to change the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're not actually checking localStorage anywhere. You also shouldn't set `show` to `'true'`, since you're trying to toggle this setting.

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $box1 = $('#box1');
    const show = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('show'));

    if (show) {
      $box1.show();
    } else {
      // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
      localStorage.setItem('show', false);
    }

    $('#chk1').click(function() {
      $box1.slideToggle('200'); 
      // toggle the boolean by negating its value
      const show = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('show'));
      localStorage.setItem('show', !show);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note that values retrieve from local storage have to be parsed as JSON, since they're given to you as a string.

And make your life easier by always properly indenting nested blocks. Much easier to read.

Comment: It's not working quite right. If I go to the page after clearing the browser the div is closed (like it suppose to be) but if I refresh the page the div is open. If I try to close it and refresh the page it still stays open.

Comment: @Freejoy yep I made an error, forgetting that `localStorage.setItem(...)` converts values to string before storing them. This means you have to either use `JSON.parse` to retrieve the original value, or just treat the values as strings. My mistake! I edited the answer.
 (It also means if you want to store an object instead of a primitive value, you have to call `JSON.stringify` on it first.)